# Dictionary casting in flatMap not working

Tags: swift

I have some old code and there is an array of type [Any]! that contains dictionaries.

```
let dictionary1: [String:Int] = [
            "one" : 1,
            "two" : 2,
            "three" : 3
        ]

let dictionary2: [String:Int] = [
            "four" : 4,
            "five" : 5,
            "six" : 6
        ]

let array: [Any]! = [dictionary1, dictionary2]
```

There's a code that stopped working.
In the flatMap closure casting to Dictionary fails and I don't know why.

```
_ = array.flatMap({$0 as! Dictionary<String, Any>})
//Cast from '[Any]' to unrelated type 'Dictionary<String, Any>' always fails
```

I found interesting thing. I think it might be related to the problem.

```
_ = print(type(of: array[0]))
//prints Dictionary<String, Int>

_ = array.flatMap({print(type(of: $0))})
//prints Array<Any>
```

I would expect that $0 and array[0] are the same objects and are of the same type.
Why the types are different?

Comment: I don’t get why you are saying `let array: [Any]!`. That’s causing the issue so why do it?

Comment: Oh, also, I know why this changed. It’s because the meaning of `!` changed and the interpretation of `flatMap` changed. This is now a different `flatMap`. In this other `flatMap`, `$0` is the array itself, unwrapped.

Comment: @matt I think this is just a MCVE that OP made up. There are many cases where you'd like a IUO, such as a property in a View Controller that you initialise in `viewDidLoad`. Though I do agree that `[Any]` should instead be `[[String: Int]]`.

Comment: @Sweeper Nevertheless the cause is that this is not the `flatMap` the old code is expecting.

Comment: This is not my code. I simplified it to be more clear.
@matt If $0 no longer returns objects from array, how can I make a specific casts for these objects if there can be other things than dictionaries inside?

Comment: What if you say `array!.flatMap...`? I think that will move things along. I think you’ll discover that this is now called `compactMap`.

Answer (score 0):

I’m going to guess that this code dates from before Swift 4.1. Back then, there were two `flatMap` methods, one for Array and one for Optional. You want the former and you’re now getting the latter (because of your use of an implicitly unwrapped Optional, which was never a great idea). The one you want is now named `compactMap`.